# Displaying a different date than is submitted rails datetime_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have several datetime_field in my application. By default, they are displaying the date as the rails format, as I dictated that for my bootstrap-datepicker:

```
format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
```

The issue: I want the date on the views to display in a different format, say:

```
'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
```

I've been scratching my head for a while on this one. Every change I make to the view side, be it by Javascript, jQuery, rails methods, helpers, whatever - they all affect the submit data, which then becomes invalid, because Rails expects the first format.

I don't want to change the default date format - we have other aspects of the website that need the database in the normal rails format. I just want to change the *display* of the date in the datetime_field, without changing the *submitted* date.

My guess would be it was an option in the datetime_field, but I can't seem to find one:

```
<%= f.datetime_field(:end_date, {?????})%>
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I think a form always submits the content of its fields. Thus, I guess you have two main options - either change the data via JS when the user licks the "submit" button, but before the actual submission; or just handle the input as a string in the backend, converting it do the right format (say, with `strptime`).

Comment: Understood,  I just hated to have to do that, because I have several date forms throughout my app - and I didn't want to have to program an exception every time. Is there no universal way?

Comment: But do you have different date formats for each form?

Comment: No, my date format that I want users to see is consistent, and the format for the controller as well - but the two are different. I have multiple date dropdowns throughout my app, and I'm just looking for a simple way to have them all do this (and any future dropdowns I create, without having to remember "oh yeah, I need six extra lines in my controller") if at all possible.

Comment: Can't you just write a one-line funcion taking the posted string and returning the rails date, such as `DateTime.strptime(formdate, '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S')`?